# Matplotlib bars don't overlap but now the axis label is missing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got my code working so that the bars don't overlap but now the labels are missing. I need them to be the trademark from my data frame. Please help me.

```
    l = np.arange(len(df6["Zeichen"]))
    print(l)
    df6.sort_values("Ø Export", inplace=True)
    plt.barh(l + 0.1, df6["Ø Export"], height=0.15, label="Ø Export", color="blue")
    plt.barh(l - 0.1, df6["Ø Import"], height=0.15, label="Ø Import", color="orange")
    plt.legend(shadow=True, loc="lower right")
    plt.xlabel("€ in Mio.")
    plt.ylabel("Warenverzeichnis")
    plt.title("Top 10 Export-Güter Ø 13 Jahre")
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: `plt.xticks(l, df6["Zeichen"])` could work here (after the last `plt.barh(...)`).

Comment: no :( this is what happens https://imgur.com/a/uVHodIt

Comment: Did you try try the y axis instead? `plt.yticks(l, df6["Zeichen"])`

Comment: xD ok thak you bro!!